# Get all rows even the filtered rows in gridpanel extjs

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I have the gridpanel in extjs with filter in the header so the end-users can make the filter, updating row and then make another filter and continue updating row ...

After finishing updating the rows, the user will click on save button and send all the data to server for updating, but i can only get the visible row in gridpanel.

Could sombody show me how can i get all the updated rows (which is hidden by filter) in gridpanel using extjs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a record is updated but not synced with the server, and the user filters the store so that the updated record is not in the result set, the updated data will be lost. IMO you should consider writing back the data immediately after editing.

Comment: The updated record is not lost, when i clear the filter in gridpanel, the data appear with the modification highlight properly. I'm using extjs 7.3 with Ext.NET 5.3.0

Comment: So you are using local filter, and not remote?

Comment: yes, I'm using local filter and the UI will looks like a big excel file with filter, user can look for the record that they need to edit using the filter feature, update the row and then hit save button to send all updated data to server for database updating. I'm struggling with how to retrieve all data changes including also the filtered out ones.

Comment: If this is only a local filter, you can try to clear the filters before saving.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try to call `sync` on the filtered store, it is possible that it will update every changed record.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, after double check the api documents from ext js, I can retrieve all records using: getDataSource function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the api document from Ext JS, I can retrieve all records including the filtered out one using getDataSource function.